# Does using new/malloc get around the warning of local pointers?

Tags: c++, pointers, warnings, compiler-warnings

I have the following code:

```
int* CoverFunction(){
    int* result =new int[3];
    result[0]=1;
    result[1]=2;
    result[2]=3;
    return result; 
}
```

This gives me the following warning:

> warning: address of local variable ‘result’ returned [-Wreturn-local-addr]

But doesn't using the new keyword mean that this shouldn't be a problem? Am I at risk of having my data erased after this function ends or will it live safely on the stack? And if it lives safely on the stack how do I get rid of the warning?

Comment: That code should not produce the warning. Is that your actual code or are you typing from memory?

Comment: That's the actual code. And yet it does produce this warning (note I use a weird version of catkin_make rather then a normal compiler).

Comment: This fixes the error (I've no idea why your compiler is complaining), but makes it the responsibility of the caller to delete the array after use. Save yourself the misery of debugging memory leaks and just use `std::vector`. Or possibly `std::array`.

Comment: if your return local variable address, then you have no guarantees that this memory will not be overwritten, newer return address of local variable. Returns only the memory address that is in the heap, ie a memory address that came with the function `malloc()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you're using new/malloc the memory is allocated from heap.

So, there is no danger of variable going out of scope in this case but still question remains who would delete that memory?

And I believe you can't get rid of that warning even if you use malloc.